# vim string replacement issue

Tags: linux, vim

I am using Linux Red Hat 5 Enterprise version. When using vi to replace string, we normally use the following command in vi -- "s/original_word/replaced_word/g", my question is, if original_word or replaced_word contains "/", how to replace?

For example, I want to replace /goo/foo/zoo to /1/2/3.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you can use a different separator, eg `:` or `,` or `;` or `|` or whatever you like
2. escape the separator if the separator is part of the search string, meaning: put a `\` before the separator, like this `s/goo\/foo\/zoo/1\/2\/3/g`

Answer (score 4):

Either use a different character for the command delimiter, or escape the slashes.

```
:s!/foo!/bar!
:s/\/foo/\/bar/
```